# How does strict convexity of $x\log x$ is used to prove that the relative entropy $H(\nu\mid\lambda)=0 \text { iff } \nu =\lambda$?

Tags: probability-theory, analysis, measure-theory, convex-analysis

1. I am having trouble using strict convexity in the lemma below to prove that
   the relative entropy $H(\nu|\lambda)=0 \text { iff } \nu =\lambda$
   [image]

Let $f(x)=x\log x$, Then strict convexity tells me that for $x \neq y, \alpha \in (0,1)$

$$f(\alpha x+(1-\alpha)y)< \alpha f(x)+(1-\alpha)f(y)$$

In the case of the problem

take $x= \phi_1 , y =\phi_2, $ in $\mathscr M_1(\mathscr S)$ (?)

$$f(\alpha \phi_1+(1-\alpha)\phi_2)< \alpha f(\phi_1)+(1-\alpha)f(\phi_2)$$

However I don't know how to relate that to $H(\nu\mid\lambda)=\int f(\phi)d\lambda$ which involves only one $\phi$. I can't take them equal because  $\phi_1 \neq \phi_2$ by assumption in the strict convexity definition.

2. Additionally I checked nonnegativity using Jensen's inequality, but I am not sure the hypothesis of Jensen holds, I would need $\phi$ to be measurable. $\phi$ looks like a Radon-Nikodym derivative, but Radon-Nikodym's theorem requires $\Lambda (A)=\int_A \phi \,d\mu$ to be absoultely continuos with respect to $\lambda$ in order for the Radon-Nikodym $\phi$ derivative to exist and be measurable

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 1):

> However I don't know how to relate that to H(ν∣λ)=∫f(ϕ)dλ
> which involves only one ϕ
> . I can't take them equal because ϕ1≠ϕ2
> by assumption in the strict convexity definition.

Strict convexity of a differentiable function $f(x)$ implies that $f(y) \gt f(x) + f'(x)(y-x) \forall x \neq y$, so taking $f(x) = x \log(x)$:

$$y \log(y) \gt x \log(x) + (1 + \log(x))(y - x) = y - x + y \log(x) $$

And with some rearranging:

$$ y \log\left(\frac{y}{x}\right) \geq y - x$$ with equality only when $y = x$. Integrating both sides with respect to the Lebesgue measure and two probability densities makes the r.h.s. vanish and the l.h.s. is zero iff the integrand is zero almost everywhere. This doesn't solve all of your problems, but hopefully separating the arguments about convexity from the concerns about measures will help with the intuition and clarity.

Comment: How do I prove tht the equality holds only for x=y and how can I apply this equation to measures?

Comment: $f(y) > f(x) + f'(x)(y - x)$ with equality iff $y = x$ follows from the definition of strict convexity and the differentiability of $f$, the second inequality is just a rearrangement of that.

Comment: I dom't see how... "Integrating both sides with respect to the Lebesgue measure and two probability densities makes the r.h.s. vanish and the l.h.s. is zero iff the integrand is zero almost everywhere". Could you elaborate on it explicitly?

Comment: $\int (p(x)p-q(x)) dx = \int p(x) dx - \int q(x) dx = 1 - 1 = 0$ since probability densities integrated over their domain equal 1. So the rhs is always zero. The integrand on the lhs is the lhs of the $y \log(y/x) \geq y - x$, and if $x \neq y$ then $y \log(y/x) \gt y - x$. The integral must be nonnegative, and the integral of the lhs can only equal the integral of the rhs if the lhs equals the rhs almost everywhere.

Comment: Why should the integrant be non-negative? the log could yield a negative value. And how does all of this apply to the problem to conclude $\phi$ is constant almost everywhere? You are working with functions but in the problem we have measures and $\phi$ which confuses me. I don't know if I have to take $\phi$ instead of x,y, p or q in your formulas.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be a random variable distributed according to measure $\lambda$. Let $\phi=\frac{d\nu}{d\lambda}$ and let $Y:=\phi(X)$. Notice that $\mathbb{E}Y=1$. By Jensen's inequality we get
$$H(\nu\vert\lambda)=\mathbb{E}(Y\log(Y))\geq \mathbb{E}Y\log\mathbb{E}Y=0\;.$$

Since $x\mapsto x\log x$ is strictly convex, the above inequality is achieved if and only if the random variable $Y$ is a constant, i.e., $\phi$ is a constant (and hence must be $\equiv 1$).

Comment: 1) Why is $\mathbb{E}Y=\int \phi(X)d\lambda =1$?  2) why   is the inequality  achieved if and only if the random variable Y  is a constant? Since the$ \mathbb{E}Y = 1$ and the $\log \mathbb{E}Y=0$, the inequality should be true regarless of Y being a constant or not 3) If Y is a constant, why is $\phi $necessarily equal to 1? Couldn't it be any other constant?

Comment: 1) $\mathbb{E}Y = \int \phi(x)d\lambda(x)=\int d\mu(x)=1$. 2) By "inequality is achieved" I mean $\mathbb{E}(Y\log Y)=\mathbb{E}Y\log\mathbb{E}Y$ if and only if $Y$ is a constant. The latter is always zero. Therefore, $\mathbb{E}(Y\log Y)\geq 0$ and $\mathbb{E}(Y\log Y)=0$ if and only if $Y$ is constant. 3) This part is not strictly needed for your original question. Suppose $\phi=c$. Since $\mu$ and $\lambda$ are both probability measures, we get $\int d\mu(x)=1=\int\phi(x)d\lambda(x)=c\int d\lambda(x)=c$.